# spark-submit using pyspark -- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommonPackage'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I am using the below project structure and keeping all reusable classes in sparkcommonlib.py in CommonPackage module.

```
 - README.rst
 - LICENSE
 - setup.py
 - requirements.txt
 - CommonPackage/__init__.py
 - CommonPackage/sparkCommonLib.py
 - CommonPackage/config.xml
 - pyspark/__init__.py
 - pyspark/SparkTableInsert.py
```

Below is the common class which set the spark session in sparkCommonLib.py for different spark applications in pyspark module.

```
class set_spark_session():
    def __init__(self , appname , master=None ):
        sparkenv = set_spark()
        appName = appname
        if master is None:
            master = sparkenv.MASTER
        self.batchsize = sparkenv.BATCH_SIZE
        self.maxpartition = sparkenv.MAX_PART
        drivers_path = os.path.normpath(sparkenv.DRIVER_PATH)
        jars = os.path.join(drivers_path, "mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar") \
               + "," + os.path.join(drivers_path, "jconn4.jar")

        self.spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", drivers_path) \
            .config("spark.jars", jars) \
            .appName(appName) \
            .master(master).getOrCreate()
```

Below is the application code which is in pyspark/sparktableinsert.py file  in pysaprk module.

```
import numpy as np , time , sys , os , pandas as pd
from CommonPackage import sparkCommonLib as sparkCommon

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = sparkCommon.set_spark_session(appname="SparkTableInsert").spark
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    log = sparkCommon.common.PrintLogInfo()
    ## Some Spark processing steps
    spark.stop()
```

When I am installing the package with pip install  , then the application is running fine , but when the same application I am running as spark-submit jobs I am getting the below error.

```
spark-submit --jars ".\CommonPackage\jars\jconn4.jar,.\CommonPackage\jars\mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar" --py-files "dependencies.zip" ".\pyspark\SparkTableInsert.py" <Arg1> <Arg2> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyspark/SparkTableInsert.py", line 2, in <module>
    **from CommonPackage import sparkCommonLib as sparkCommon**
```

I have tried to add the full application egg or zip file which was created using *"python setup.py sdist"* but same result.

```
spark-submit --jars ".\CommonPackage\jars\jconn4.jar,.\CommonPackage\jars\mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar" --py-files "SparkTableInsert-0.0.0.zip" ".\pyspark\SparkTableInsert.py" <arg1> <arg2>                                                                                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyspark/SparkTableInsert.py", line 2, in <module>
    **from CommonPackage import sparkCommonLib as sparkCommon**
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommonPackage'

spark-submit --jars ".\CommonPackage\jars\jconn4.jar,.\CommonPackage\jars\mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar" --py-files "dependencies.zip" --archives "SparkTableInsert-0.0.0.zip" ".\pyspark\SparkTableInsert.py" <arg1> <arg2>                                                                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyspark/SparkTableInsert.py", line 2, in <module>
    from CommonPackage import sparkCommonLib as sparkCommon
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommonPackage'

spark-submit --jars ".\CommonPackage\jars\jconn4.jar,.\CommonPackage\jars\mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar" --archives "SparkTableInsert-0.0.0.zip"  --py-files "dependencies.zip" ".\pyspark\SparkTableInsert.py" <arg1> <arg2>                                                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyspark/SparkTableInsert.py", line 2, in <module>
    from CommonPackage import sparkCommonLib as sparkCommon
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommonPackage'
```

I tried with adding the following lines in ./pyspark/SparkTableInsert.py but same error is giving.

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("SparkTableInsert-0.0.0.zip")
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("dependencies.zip")
```

I am testing spark-submit on my local machine before pushing it to Google Spark jobs to run in Google cluster.

Comment: It might be because when you pip install packages, it might have been installed in the python Lib /site packages. So, spark-submits which might have been in different directories, cannot access the package. So try pip installing again but this time, do - `pip install --target/[directory where spark-submits is present] CommonPackage`

Comment: As i mentioned I need to run this in google cluster , hence need a way to submit spark jobs without pip install on that cluster.